# ToLowerCase in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: javascript

The following gives 0 in Firefox. However it gives -1 in chrome.

```
var index = "İSTANBUL".toLowerCase().indexOf("is");
console.log(index);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/81f0yr8w/1/

Chrome puts an extra character when **lower casing İ** (latin capital letter i with a dot above "\u0130")

```
"İ".toLocaleLowerCase().length
>2
```

Is it a normal behaviour?

Comment: Something strange is indeed happening. In Chrome: `"İSTANBUL".length === 8` and `"İSTANBUL".toLowerCase().length === 9`. It adds a hidden character.

Comment: "İSTANBUL".toLowerCase().charCodeAt(1) === 775  but "İ" and "i" are two very different characters.  the first has a COMBINING DOT ABOVE when lowercased. (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You can encode the string first then compare it. This will yield the same result in Firefox and Chrome.

```
// 0 Chrome // 0 Firefox
encodeURIComponent("İSTANBUL".toLowerCase()).indexOf(encodeURIComponent("İS".toLowerCase()))
```

The fact that Firefox and Chrome handle it differently is strange. But strange is defined by w3c spec here: https://www.w3.org/TR/charmod-norm/#matchingAlgorithm fwiw, you have to lowercase the string first then encode it. They won't match unless they're the same case first.

Found the [Firefox Bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=633440) and marked duplicate of [812837]. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=812837) It was reported in 2011 and it's still open. So I guess it's not a priority.

Comment: "İSTANBUL".toLowerCase().indexOf("İS".toLowerCase()) is also gives me zero. There is no need a encodeUriComponent, I need to add extra replacements in my actual code like replacing İ with i :) But this case is strange isnt it...